# Laravel Eloquent - count

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table named project which has a column named status, it takes 4 values : created, active, done, cancelled.
I want to get a count object of each status in one query if it's possible :

```
[
    "created" : 5,
    "active" : 34,
    "done" : 7,
    "cancelled" : 5
]
```

Comment: what's the type of the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it in one query by doing this.

```php
    $status = Project::select('status')->get();

    $result = $status->groupBy('status')->map(fn ($v) => $v->count());

    $status->count(); //total count,
    $result // this is the result you want.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it via raw query

```
$rows = DB::select('SELECT count(*) as cnt, status_id FROM `projects` WHERE 1 group by status');
```

result:

```
array:5 [
  0 => {
    "cnt": 1
    "status": 'status1'
  }
  1 => {
    "cnt": 882
    "status": 'status2'
  }
]
```

to convert in your structure

```
$data = [];
foreach ($row as $row) {
   $data[$row->status] = $row->cnt;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to get the total count also?

Comment: in one query no I think, but you can do it inside loop